# Build a Presence Map using bits of bytes in java

Tags: java, bit, bit-shift

I have a requirement in Java where I need to build codec for `Bit Map` for `n` number of bytes. Each bit of byte will indicate presence of a field.

We already know the position of each field i.e. which bit position will represent which field.

Example:

```
bit position: field
0:TYPE
1:SIDE
2:QUANTITY
3:PRICE
.
.
.
25:TIF
```

Now, if user specify in value some of these types, example:

```
String value = "TYPE,SIDE,TIF";
```

I need to encode the presence of this field in byte and add it in `bytebuffer` and then I need to get bytes from this `bytebuffer` and decode it and I should get only these fields.

The total bytes used will vary, might be 4, 6, 8.

Can someone provide me solution for this.

Comment: The code is properly encoding and i can see the binary output of bytes: 
01001011
00000011
00000100
00000000
00000000

But i m sure this code can drastically improved and there I need help

Comment: Please see the link for Code:
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=939F3953D7642024!112&authkey=!AM1SbQFxsdgdHNI&ithint=folder%2c

Answer (score 0):

Use an **enum** form the bit positions. The `ordinal()` gives the index, the `getName()` the string presentation, and the static `valueOf(String)` the parsing from String to enum.

```
enum Field {
    TYPE, SIDE, QUANTITY, PRICE, ..., TIF;

    public static COUNT = values().length;
}
```

When using a [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) with the enum:

```
BitSet fieldPresences = new BitSet(Field.COUNT);
fieldPresences.set(Field.QUANTITY.ordinal(), true);
Field field = Field.valueOf("QUANTITY");
```

However you can better use **[EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html)** which is as efficient too:

```
Set<Field> presentFields = EnumSet<Field>.of(Field.TYPE, Field.PRICE);
```

---

***Alternative to code given later in the question:***

The code is fine enough.
I have used `PresenceMapCodec` which can be given any enum class.

```
PresenceMapCodec<Fields> codec = new PresenceMapCodec<Fields>(Fields.class);
String userInput = "ClientOrderID,SubmittingBrokerID,SecurityIDSource,"
        + "TransactionTime,OriginalClientOrderID,OrderID,OrderCapacity";
Set<Fields> fieldset = codec.encode(userInput);
String decodedValue = codec.decode(fieldset);

public enum Fields {
    ClientOrderID, SubmittingBrokerID, SecurityID, SecurityIDSource,
    SecurityExchange, BrokerLocationID, TransactionTime, Side,
    OriginalClientOrderID, OrderID, OwningBrokerID, OrderType, Price,
    OrderQuantity, TIF, PositionEffect, OrderRestrictions, MaxPriceLevels,
    OrderCapacity, Text, ExecutionID
}

public class PresenceMapCodec<E extends Enum<E>> {

    private final Class<E> enumClass;

    public PresenceMapCodec(Class<E> enumClass) {
        this.enumClass = enumClass;
    }

    public String decode(Set<E> fieldset) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (E field : fieldset) {
            sb.append(field.name()).append(',');
        }
        if (sb.length() != 0) {
            sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1); // Remove trailing comma.
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public Set<E> encode(String value_) {
        Set<E> results = EnumSet.noneOf(enumClass);
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(value_, ",");
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String token = st.nextToken().trim();
            E field = E.valueOf(enumClass, token);
            // valueOf can throw IllegalArgumentException.
            results.add(field);
        }
        return results;
    }

    public String decode(ByteBuffer byteBuffer_) {
        E[] constants = enumClass.getEnumConstants();
        int byteCount = (constants.length + 7) / 8;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[byteCount];
        byteBuffer_.get(bytes);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < constants.length; ++i) {
            int b = bytes[i / 8];
            int mask = 1 << (i % 8);
            if ((b & mask) != 0) {
                if (sb.length() != 0) {
                    sb.append(',');
                }
                sb.append(constants[i].name());
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public void encode(String value_, ByteBuffer byteBuffer_) {
        Set<E> fieldset = encode(value_);
        E[] constants = enumClass.getEnumConstants();
        int byteCount = (constants.length + 7) / 8;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[byteCount];
        for (E field : fieldset) {
            int i = field.ordinal();
            bytes[i / 8] |= 1 << (i % 8);
        }
        byteBuffer_.put(bytes);
    }
}
```

Below the hood the same bit fiddling happens, though a bit more layered.

If you have wrong input something like the following happens:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
        No enum constant presensemap_v2.Fields.xxSubmittingBrokerID
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)
    at presensemap_v2.PresenceMapCodec.encode(PresenceMapCodec.java:33)
    at presensemap_v2.PresenceMapDemo.main(PresenceMapDemo.java:14)
```

Comment: Please see above link for Code.

Comment: Okay, I have done it - shameslessly stealing from your code. As you see it is a bit more compact, and allows Fields.ClientOrderID and Set operations like `containsAll`. The name Fields maybe better should be singular Field. To receive the bytes: EnumSet unfortunately not exposes its internals, and then `BitSet` and `ordinal()` must come to help.

Comment: Hey Joop, I didn't understood ur solution. I need to encode fields presence in bits of bytes and these bytes need to add in bytebuffer which will be sent on connection and then decodes these bytes to know fields. How to do that?  Do you think the code that i have written is good enough?

Comment: Added the ByteBuffer methods in my style. Your code is fine. Only the comma treatment would fail on the empty input string.

Comment: Thanks Joop, i did performance comparison and can see both performed almost same.

Comment: Oh, do not underestimate your code w.r.t. efficiency, my code might be shorter and using available production quality classes, but is more layered. And your code uses micro-optimizations, like on the bit counters, and not using a `byte[]`. Bye.